# Get the user status in WooCommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I have a custom plugin that calls an API and adds some additional things to my orders at Woocommerce platform.

I had three scenarios before:

- first time purchase, uses data submitted from the checkout form fields is used, e.g., `$_POST['account_phone']`, and everything went fine
- subsequent purchases used the same principle
- renewals used the order data from the initial orders, and acted like a single purchase is made

Now, the API has changed a bit and several new methods are available, which changes the scenario options above:

- first time purchases go into two categories, new users at the API site, and existing users at the API site but new to this platform
- remaining is the same

I have issue with the purchases for existing users of this site. First time purchase sends a request to the API, using the `POST` parameters. However, if a user is already registered, those parameters, like his cell phone number, should be read from the billing data he/she already entered. Thus, I need a way to tell the WooCommerce is this new user trying to buy something and registering, **or** that this is an already existing user that has his or her data entered. I can get this data from the initial order, or user's billing info, but can't figure out how to check what type of order is it and where WooCommerce should get those values from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this via another way. The `$fields['account']['account_phone']` was shown only during the registration, and simple change of that to `$fields['billing']['account_phone']` makes that field "belong" to billing info, which is always shown, which is very convenient and makes no difference later when I check for input there.